# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

I had this same project working in VS2010, however when I switched to VS2013 I can no longer connect to the same Oracle DB. 
Steps that I have taken so far:

Installed Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013

Nuget - Installed Official Oracle ODP.NET Manager Driver

Nuget - Installed Official Oracle ODP.NET Managed Entity Framework Driver

Nuget - Installed Official Oracle Providers for ASP.NET Managed Driver

I can in VS2013 go to Data Connections and connect to the Oracle DB server that I desire. So it appears that the drivers appear to be working.

However I am unsure why I can't connect in my DAL.

I have code like:

```
using (OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection(_connString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = CreateOracleCommand(oConn, "GET_USERS", CommandType.StoredProcedure))
                {
                    oConn.Open();
```

Where is the _connString is:

```
<add name="OracleTest" connectionString="Data Source=<SID>;User Id=<user>;Password=<password>;"/>
```

Comment: Where is your `tnsnames.ora`, resp. `sqlnet.ora` file? Set an environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` for this directory. ODP.NET Manager Driver does not read the `TNS_ADMIN` value from Registry. Check your `machine.config` file, perhaps it has been modified by VS 2013

Comment: machine.config has not been changed.  I only see the tnsnames and sqlnet files in the OracleDeveloperToolsForVS2013\network\admin directory.  They appear to have been created when I installed the developer tools.  I'm assuming VS2010 accesses the DB differently then VS2013 does?  I utilized the same drivers in both projects.

Comment: Are the tnsnames and sqlnet files in OracleDeveloperToolsForVS2013\network\admin directory the correct ones? Which files are used by VS2010 (obviously not OracleDeveloperToolsForVS2013\network\admin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Tools for VS2013 is required if you want to use EF.

I got the ADO connection working again by changing the connection string from the simple server/username/password to the one that matches in TNSNAMES.ORA.

This will also work when you set the TNSNAMES.ORA in the oracle tools path and you go to setup an EF connection.

However I'm not sure what headaches this will cause me when I go to deploy.  I would think it would be a much better solution if I could just use the EZ Connect setup when establishing a connection. (That I can't get to work at this time)

Comment: Actually it is a partial solution.  I do have to install Oracle Tools for VS2013 in order to have the driver available to set up an Entity Framework connection.  However as soon as I installed the tools I';m back to square one again. The ADO and EF both generate the same error again.

Comment: Maybe try to install the odp.net from Oracle page instead of nuGet

Answer (score 2):

ODP.NET Manager Driver tries to resolve the datasource TNS from following:

1. data source alias in the 'dataSources' section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.
4. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present at `%TNS_ADMIN%`
   (where `%TNS_ADMIN%` is an environment variable setting).
5. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present at `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`
   (where `%ORACLE_HOME%` is an environment variable setting).

Check each of them for VS2010 and VS2013. At some point there must be a difference.

**Correction Update:**

According this statement [Oracle Managed and TNS Names](https://community.oracle.com/message/10610812#10610812) (posted by 
Alex Keh - Product Manager-Oracle) list above was only valid for ODP.NET Managed Driver **beta version**.

According official documentation [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161)
ODP.NET Managed Driver uses this path:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file.
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

Comment: OK.  I don't see a difference in #1.  Ideally I would like to configure my app in this way.
I don't see TNS_ADMIN in either project.
No tnsnames.ora in the exe
No %TNS_ADMIN% environment variable
I do see %ORACLE_HOME% variable.  It points to the Oracle client.  Since I'm running both projects on the same machine they would both be pointing to the same thing correct?

Comment: It's something to do with the Oracle developer tools.  As soon as I uninstall my ADO connections work.  (No driver for EF though).  When I install those tools then I can no longer connect to the DB.  (Trying the simple conn string as well as the one listed in the answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using the tnsnames file.  Using tns-less connections are more portable in my opinion.

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)  (PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Yes, if you have your own small environment under your control. If you have a "remote" IT Database department hosting 100 Oracle databases in virtual servers, then the tns-less connection can be quite cumbersome and you better rely on a tnsnames.ora file or even a LDAP server.